# Git Bash - Gulp: Can't execute command "gulp"; Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, git, bash, twitter-bootstrap, gulp

I'm following a Udemy Tutorial on Bootstrap.
I'm inside the folder `C:/bs4projects/bs4starter` in Git Bash but when I run the command "`gulp`", it will give me this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js
```

I noticed that it's adding an extra folder called **"`c`"** on the path
and I don't know how to change the `PATH` of where it should should look
for.
I also noticed that it isn't looking for `gulp.js` that is inside my `bs4starter` folder.
Please help, been trying to find solutions all day.

I checked my `gulp.js` both installed in my `bs4starter` folder and in
`\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli` folder and they're both there so I think I
installed it correctly.

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

In Git bash, check your $PATH

```
echo $PATH
```

You can fix it with

```
export PATH=/c/Users[username]/AppData/Roaming/npm/node-modules/gulp-cli/bin:...(rest of the $PATH)
```

Comment: @Argh What is your PATH *before* exporting it? (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/c/Users/`argh/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/`argh/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files/Broadcom/Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Brackets/command:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/

Comment: This is my first time using command prompt since I'm following a tutorial on Udemy so I don't really have any knowledge on plugins. Sorry

Comment: this saved me on a windows machine after updating to gulp 4.  My git bash was looking in an incorrect place for the global gulp and it was breaking all my updated gulp scripts.  I hade to add the /AppData/Roaming/npm to the path variable